# I want to label a row based on string

Tags: python, string, dataframe, label

| A |
| --- |
| Orange |
| Apple |
| Orange |
| Pineapple |
| Apple |

Here, I want to convert the dataframe into like this. If 'Orange' present in A column then label it as 1 then following row also as 1. If again 'Orange' coming then label as 2 then following row also 2. Like wise I want to label for many records.

| A | label |
| --- | --- |
| Orange | 1 |
| Apple | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Pineapple | 2 |
| Apple | 2 |

Please help me to write a code for many records in python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just do `df["label"] = df["A"].eq("Orange").cumsum()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution!

```py
import pandas as  pd


def my_func(arg):
    return {
        "Apple" : "1", # or int
        "Orange" : "2", 
        "Pineapple" : "3" 
    }.get(arg, "N.D.")

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["Apple", "Orange","Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"]})

df["Label"] = df["A"].apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

```
           A Label
0      Apple     1
1     Orange     2
2      Apple     1
3     Orange     2
4  Pineapple     3
```